# Извлечение ip-адреса из произвольной строки на языке java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка, содержащая множество символов. В ней содержится ip-адрес. Мне нужен код, который извлекает из неё ip-адрес и возвращает в виде строки. Мой код возвращает строку только, если вся строка text состоит из ip-адреса, в чём ошибка?

```
    String text = "avcavf 213.123.11.255aoegger";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[01]?\\d\\d?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[01]?\\d\\d?)$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not found");
    }
```

Comment: А если такое регулярное выражение? Не подходит? (\d{0,3}\.){3}\d{0,3}

Comment: `^` => `(?<!\\d)`, `$` => `(?!\\d)`

Answer (score 5):

Так?

```
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class IpHelp {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            printFind(
                    "avcavf 213.123.11.255aoegger",
                    "54.34.23.43asdsad sddas sagf a",
                    "@@$H%KJ@%54.342.23.43asdsad sddas sagf a",
                    "asdsa54.34.23.143d sddas sagf a"
            );
        }

        private static void printFind(String... lines) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{0,3}\\.){3}\\d{0,3}");
            for (String s : lines) {
                Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
                if (m.find()) {
                    System.out.println(m.group());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Not found");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

213.123.11.255
54.34.23.43
54.342.23.43
54.34.23.143

Comment: Да, именно. Благодарю!

Comment: @AlbertIdrisov Как вы видите, предлагаемое выражение находит подстроку `54.342.23.43`, которая не является IP-адресом. Оно [также найдёт `...`](https://regex101.com/r/2d2zKa/1).

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Из задачи я предположил, что в строках находятся валидные ip. Если нет, то само собой нужно допилить строку поиска.

Comment: @ezhov_da В уже имеющемся коде всё есть, не надо менять саму суть выражения. Просто проверку контекста надо было исправить.

Comment: Можно попробовать так: ([12]?[0-9]?[0-9]\.){3}([12]?[0-9]?[0-9])

Comment: См. [**мой ответ с корректным решением**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/837972/182013). Писать свое [регулярное выражение для IP-адреса](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html) - это изобретать велосипед.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew в моём конкретном случае на входе всё-таки даются строки, содержащие валидные ip-адреса. Поэтому первоначально данное решение мне подходит. И всё же спасибо Вам за участие!

Comment: @AlbertIdrisov Тогда зачем вы указали в заголовке "из **произвольной** строки"? В общем, данный ответ не соответствует вопросу.

Answer (score 1):

В исходном выражении `^` ищет начало строки, а `$` - конец строки. Нужно заменить `^` на `(?<!\\d)`  (сразу перед не должно быть цифры), а `$` на `(?!\\d)` (сразу после не должно быть цифры).

В коде лучше заменить длинные повторяющиеся шаблоны переменной для "удобочитаемости":

```
String text = "avcavf 213.123.11.255aoegger";
String octet = "(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[01]?\\d\\d?)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\d)" + octet + "(?:\\." + octet +"){3}(?!\\d)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
System.out.println(m.find() ? m.group() : "Not found");
```

[Демо на Java](https://ideone.com/j1bdSR)

[Демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/3fZcpG/1)